# How to substring Android logcat output and show only the message itself

Tags: android, adb, android-logcat

I would like to use logcat and output only the messages themselves.
Not the method name, not the time, not the tag - just the message.

Example, from this message:

> D/ConnectivityService(  471): Setting tx/rx TCP buffers to
>   524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576

I only want the

> Setting tx/rx TCP buffers to
>   524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576

Is that possible ?

Comment: Do you want to do that in post-processing, or are you asking how to get the logs to appear like that initially?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logcat has a format parameter, one of which is the message alone with no metadata.

```
adb logcat -v raw
```

You can still apply filters after this, e.g. `*:S ConnectivityService:D`, even though the tag is no longer part of the output.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After opening your Logcat (Inside Android Studio), on the left side you will see menu icons, select the Settings one and you can check which information you would like to see in the Logcat.

[image: You can see this image for reference.]

Comment: This almost works. He wanted just the message, yet this has the priority added ("D: " for debug priority, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Jake Wharton's [Pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do `adb logcat -v raw` to get rid of the tags and use pipe `| grep -i ""` to substring that output **if** you know what you're searching for. Otherwise, **ephemient**'s answer is perfect. Does that answer your questions (as it seemed to be twofold)?